# Redirecionamento 301 condicional por IP para outro domínio

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Gostaria de redirecionar todos usuários que acessarem determinada página de um domínio para a mesma página de outro domínio, exceto a mim mesmo, pensei em utilizar o redirecionamento condicional por IP da [seguinte maneira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8985554) através do arquivo *.htaccess*:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.456.789.000
RewriteRule .* http://dominionovo.com.br/ [R=301,L]
```

Neste caso todos usuários que navegarem pelo site atual, serão redirecionados para a mesma página em *dominionovo.com.br* desde que o IP do mesmo seja diferente de *123.456.789.000* (meu ip atual).

Aparentemente funcionou como esperado, exceto quando a página do domínio atual é chamada através de um iframe no domínio novo.

O código acima foi uma adaptação por conta própria, não sei se é a maneira correta de fazer isso. Errei em alguma parte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez esteja faltando o passar o parâmetro do caminho atual para a URL, faça assim:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://dominionovo.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Se quiser redirecionar as querystrings talvez seja necessário adicionar a flag `QSA`, assim:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://dominionovo.com.br/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Funcionou como deveria, obrigado.